# facet_grid2 add headers to top and bottom rows

Tags: r, ggplot2, header, facet-grid, ggh4x

Given the below data:

```
df <- data.frame(group = rep(c('A', 'B', 'C'), each = 5),
           treatment = rep(c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), 3)) %>%
  left_join(data.frame(group = rep(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), each = 4),
                       level = rep(1:4, 4))) 
df$header <- df$treatment
df$header[df$group == 'C'] <- paste0(df$treatment, 'extra')
df$est <- rnorm(nrow(df))
df$ci_lower <- df$est - runif(nrow(df), 0,0.7)
df$ci_upper <- df$est + runif(nrow(df), 0,0.7)
```

I can make a facetted plot with `treatment` values across columns and `group` values across rows:

```
ggplot(df, aes(y = level)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linewidth = 0.3, colour = "black", linetype = "dotted") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(xmin = ci_lower, xmax = ci_upper), position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), width = 0, linewidth = 0.5) +
  geom_point(aes(x = est), fill = 'white', position = position_dodge(width = 0.8)) +
  ggh4x::facet_grid2(group ~ treatment, scales = 'free', independent = 'y', render_empty = FALSE) +
  ylab('') + xlab('Estimated AMCE') +
  ggh4x::force_panelsizes(rows = c(1, 0.4, 0.4)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

But what I would like is to add an additional column header on top of the third row using `header` values, so it looks like this:

[image]

Is this possible to do under `ggh4x`? If not, is there any other alternative?

One option is to just plot the third row plots separately but that changes the axis range and panel size as well. I'm hoping there's an easier solution to this.

Comment: There isn't any option to do this in `ggh4x::facet_grid2()`. My advise is to use plot composition using patchwork. If you want to harmonise panel limits, you can use `ggh4x::scale_x_facet()` for example.